# Receiving notification about any child changes

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm building a document-like model using Realm for Swift. My schema is roughly following:

```
Document
|
+- root: Group
   |
   +- children: [Node]
      +- Text: Node
      +- Image: Node
      +- Group: Node
```

For example:

```
Document
|
+- root
  |
  +- text
  |
  +- group
  |  |
  |  +- image
  |  |
  |  +- text
  |
  +- text
```

Every time any of arbitrary deeply nested children changes I want to be notified which object exactly has changed so  I can prune the view tree representing that node and redraw it using the latest data

It seems like observing changes on a given `RLMObject` notifies only about immediate property changes, while observing all the changes on `RLMRealm` doesn't report what actually's changed.

Is there an API that I'm missing?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to RLMObject and RLMRealm, you can also observe changes on collections. Add a notification block to the collection property Document.root.children. You might also fetch/query RLMObjects of type Node, and add a notification block to the RLMResults object.

See https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest#collection-notifications for more.

One limitation is that you won’t know what property within the object caused the notification to fire, only which object changes. There’s an open GitHub issue about this: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3485

Comment: Thanks, it appears that realm is not going to work out for me because it has a limitation of 16 levels depth according to https://twitter.com/Adam_Fish/status/947095823095123968